# Discard Bipartite Edges on igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph, bipartite

I am looking to discard bipartite edges on iGraph so that I am only seeing those with greater than 3 memberships. I am looking at a dataset of `student`s who have attended `classes`. I want to only see a graph of classes where the connections are based on if there are more than 3 students per class.

```
students | class
Jane     | Biology
Jack     | Biology
Mark     | Biology
Steve    | Biology
Jane     | Chemistry
Jack     | Chemistry
Mark     | Chemistry
Steve    | Chemistry
Lane     | Physics
Steve    | Physiology
```

I want in the end to have a graph of just `Biology` and `Chemistry` with a line drawn between them as both these classes have a student membership > 3

Here is what I have so far:

```
g.students
cl<- clusters(g.students)
g.students<- delete.vertices(g.students, names(cl$membership[ cl$membership > 3]))
```

Somehow, when I input this, I am getting this back which can't be because there should be nodes and edges:

```
IGRAPH c2cf5c3 UN-B 1 0 --
```

`+ attr: name (v/c), type (v/l)`

I'm not sure why this is.. Is there a different way to discard these edges?

Comment: So no Physics and Physiology at all? Then it sounds like, in general, the final result would be a complete graph with the vertices being classes of >3 students. Is that right?

Comment: To continue the question of @Julius Do you want all nodes connected or do  you only want two classes connected if they share students?

Comment: Yes that is correct and yes I want to only represent the edges where the two classes share more than 3 students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
A <- as_adj(g.students) # Extracting the adjacency matrix
B <- as.matrix(A[unique(df$class), unique(df$students)]) # Selecting its relevant part
C <- B %*% t(B) # Numbers of common students between classes
C <- ifelse(C > 3, 1, 0) * (1 - diag(nrow(C))) # Setting diagonal to zero, discarding 
                                               # edges, and setting remaining weights to 1
C <- C[colSums(C) > 0, colSums(C) > 0]         # Discarding vertices
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(C)            # Obtaining a graph
```